# PostgreSQL password authentication failed for user "app"

Tags: .net, postgresql, docker, npgsql

I have a .NET 7 app that uses NPGSQL (v7.0.2) to connect to a PostgreSQL DB (v15.2) running in Docker. The image is pulled directly from https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres. The .NET app is not running in a container.

The container is started with:

```
docker run --name db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

Login with `psql -U postgres -h localhost` works as expected.
Once the container is started, I create a database and user inside the container:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH TEMPLATE template0;
CREATE ROLE app WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO app;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO app;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO app;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO app;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO app;
```

Config from the .NET appsettings.json is:

```
  {
    "Host": "localhost",
    "Database": "mydb",
    "Username": "app",
    "Password": "password"
  }
```

When I run the .NET app, the logs show:

```
Severity: FATAL
    SqlState: 28P01
    MessageText: password authentication failed for user "app"
    File: auth.c
    Line: 326
    Routine: auth_failed
```

PostgreSQL container logs show:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "app"
DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

I can login with `psql -U app -h localhost -d mydb`

I've tried starting the container specifying different auth methods:

```
docker run ... -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--auth=scram-sha-256
docker run ... -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--auth=md5
docker run ... -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--auth=password
```

I've also tried changing the matching line in pg_hba.config to:

```
host all all all md5
host all all all password
```

If I change the .NET config to use the postgres user, it works.

```
{
   "Host": "localhost",
   "Database": "mydb",
   "Username": "postres",
   "Password": ""
}
```

For reference, here is the pg_hba.conf from the container (/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf)

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all scram-sha-256
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the password is not getting transmitted correctly through .net.  Maybe it has special characters which need to be escaped somehow.  Try creating a password with nothing but letters and numbers.  No one is ever going to guess 'jaichoongai5EGhie0xahvu3u'  Unless they read this comment.

Comment: "I've also tried changing the matching line in pg_hba.config to:"  That will be ineffective unless you reset the password so it no longer was stored in the SCRAM format.  If you did do that, then what was the new error message in the server log?

Comment: @jjanes I tried a couple of simple passwords (e.g. 'password'), with no luck.